# Get All Bookmarks from Word Document - android

Tags: android

is it possible to get all bookmarks from Word Document in the android ?

I need to extract all bookmarks from a word document so I can store them.

is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use either JODConverter(Java API). Infos are available here:
http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter

Here is an example for doing that with JODConverter:

```
 File docFile = new File(“document.doc”);
 File htmlFile = new File(“document.html”);
 // connect to an OpenOffice.org 
 OpenOfficeConnection openConnection = new SocketOpenOfficeConnection(8100);
 openConnection.connect();

 DocumentConverter converter = new OpenOfficeDocumentConverter(openConnection);
 converter.convert(docFile, htmlFile);
 // close the connection
 openConnection.disconnect();

 //Finally read the HTML from the htmlFile. You can read it as a String
```

Or the TextMining Extractors. It's a Java API available on Maven. To use this API, add the following into your Gradle file:

```
'org.textmining:tm-extractors:0.4'
```

If you are using Maven, add in your pom file the following artifacts:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.textmining</groupId>
  <artifactId>tm-extractors</artifactId>
  <version>0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Or if you just want to use the JAR, downloaded from here:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.textmining/tm-extractors/0.4

Comment: I think JODConverter is an API for windows platform.  is it possible post an example from TextMining Extractors ?

Comment: @S.M_Emamian on the URL that I've added on my response is mentioning that the "JODConverter can be used as a Java library, embedded in your own Java application". Click here to read more: http://www.artofsolving.com/node/16.html

Comment: @S.M_Emamian Did you manage to convert the word document to HTML and then read it as String?